# How to add a variable in the regex flutter

Tags: regex, flutter

I don't found how to add variable in a regex

for example I have a String who is an output of list

MyString ="list:[2020-09-05 12:23, 2020-09-04 12:23]"

I use regex to extract date match = 2020-09-05

But I don't found how to add this match variable in other regex area expression, like that:

RegExp regExp = new RegExp(
r'((Prefix`$match`)[1-9]\S(,suffix))',);

Answer (score 0):

If your list is filled with those types of elements, I would use

```
var element = string.splits(' ').first;
```

Comment: I don't understand this approach, I add more information in my Post. Sorry for confusing, but my List is in fact a String but with the output of a List. I did the job to extract date from this list but need to add this extracted date in a new regex to match specific data from the date I have extract. But regex seems to only accept static or text but not variable in the expression area

Comment: I think I found but not sur, if I use this + match + it's seems to be accepted but after add this I have \S who change color ( before green like text, after orange )